# C++ - New and Delete with Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I am trying to correct a memory leak and cannot figure out why the delete array [] is not working. I tried searching other posts but I am stuck, so I am hoping I can be pointed in the right direction.

I am trying to reallocate the memory but I keep breaking the code when I use the delete array [].

Here is an example of what the output looks like and what I am trying to achieve: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcZiJ.png)

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    int* nArray = new int[arraySize];
    cout << "After creating and allocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        nArray[i] = i*i;
    }
    cout << "After initializing nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << "  nArray[" << i << "] = " << nArray[i] << " at address <" << nArray+i << ">" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Before reallocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << endl;
    nArray = new int[arraySize + 2];
    cout << dec << "After reallocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize+2; i++)
    {
        nArray[i] = i*i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have already explored this option, but I wanted to check, why not use std::vector<int> for what you are trying to do above?

Comment: There is no `delete` in the code you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new pointer that points to a larger memory block. So have a new pointer where `nArray2 = new int[arraySize + 2];` happens, but keep old nArray. Now, copy over content of nArray to the new pointer. After you copied you can `delete[] nArray`. But now you have to use your new pointer, or set `nArray` to point to this new array.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arraySize=10;

    int* nArray = new int[arraySize];

    //init array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        nArray[i] = i*i;
    }

    //simple realocation    
    //create bigger array
    int newArraySize = arraySize + 2;
    int* newNArray = new int[newArraySize];

    //copy old array to now one (truncate if smaler)
    for (int i = 0; i < (arraySize<newArraySize?arraySize:newArraySize); i++)
    {
        newNArray[i] = nArray[i];
    }

    //init new elements
    for (int i = arraySize; i < newArraySize; i++)
    {
        newNArray[i] = i*i;
    }

    //delete old array
    delete [] nArray;

    //set pointer to new array
    nArray = newNArray;
    //set new size for array
    arraySize = newArraySize;

    return 0;
}
```

[cpp.sh/96bi](http://cpp.sh/96bi)